# Dúvida com algoritmo e vetor

Tags: java, algoritmo

me ajudem a resolver o seguinte algoritmo. No caso, é um vetor de 20 posições. A minha duvida é quais os valores estariam armazenados no vetor A?

```
for (i=1, A[0]=1; i< A.lenght; i++)
    A[i] = A[i-1]*2;
```

Resposta correta:

> a - Elementos do tipo 3i para i
>   b - Elementos do tipo 2i para i
>   c - Elementos do tipo i2 para i
>   d - Elementos do tipo ii para i

Poderiam me explicar qual é a resposta correta?

Comment: A B e a C não são a mesma reposta?

Comment: essa é uma pergunta que caiu em um concurso passado.

Comment: A segunda e a terceira opção estão iguais, e as duas são as corretas. Tem algo errado ai

Comment: Mas a B e a C são a mesma coisa mesmo.

Comment: A não ser que a C seja `Elementos do tipo i² para i`, o que é uma coisa completamente diferente do que está agora.

Answer (score 0):

Bem, é fácil, vamos por partes.

Desmembrando o for **`i = 1, A[0] = 1`**. Esta instrução inicializa `i` como `0` e a primeira posição de `A` como `1`.

Depois disso é só um for normal. A condição, **`i < A.lenght`** que é "execute isto enquanto `i` for menor que comprimento do *array* A. E o `i++` que é o incremento de `i` em 1 a cada *loop*.

O código do *loop* (**`A[i] = A[i-1]*2`**) é o seguinte.

A posição `i` do *array* vai receber o valor da posição anterior do *array* multiplicado por 2. Ou seja, respostas B e C estão corretas.